# Repeat random placing of ships in battleship, depending on restrictions

Tags: python-2.7, random

I'm creating a battleship field and I have created a method that creates spots based off of random parameters. The spots would be like the "1a", "2a" setup.

Here's what it looks like when you call it

```
ships.append(place_ship(ships, randint(2,3), letter, str(randint(1,4)), random.choice([True,False])))
```

randint(2,3) refers to the length of the ship, the random choice parameter is whether the boat is vertical or not, the letter refers to the random letter from this:

```
letter = ''
while letter != "a" and letter != "b" and letter != "c":
    letter = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

The method that creates it is place_ships:

```
def place_ship(ships, length, x, y, vert):
idk = {}
for i in range(length):
    square = y+x
    if vert:
        x = chr(ord(x) + 1)
    else:
        y = str(int(y) + 1)
    idk[i] = square
return idk
```

My question is how to place the ships without having any of the spots cross ships.

Here is an example of what the locations in a list look like:

```
['2c', '2d', '3c', '4c', '2c', '2d']
```

So 2c,2d is a ship 3c,4c, then 2c,2d

I've tried to do the following, but it only checks the first ship

```
for i in all_ship_loc:
    occurence = all_ship_loc.count(i)
    while occurence > 1:
        place_ship(ships, randint(2,3), letter, str(randint(1,4)),random.choice([True,False]))
```

Thanks!

Comment: the naive (and easy to implement) way is to try to place ships repeatedly, rejecting layouts with overlaps.

Comment: You could improve the while - `while not letter in {"a", "b", "c"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to cretate a dictionary for every possible place, so you check if the generated position is already occuped.

```
dict = { "a1" : True } # True is occuped
```

Or you could use a list but with only the occuped places.

Answer (score 1):

You might store a matrix of occupied places (values `0`,`1`). Placing a ship occupies some elements (spots where the ship is located, adjacent etc.). For a given ship size, and a given row/column you easely can find out amount of positions available. So your alogorithm may be as follows:

- starting from biggest ship
- randomly choose a direction (horisontal/vertical)
- enumerate positions available in that direction
- if none available, reposition some last ships
- choose a random position within available set, mark corresponding spots occupied